# How to sort the following numbers in ascending order?

Tags: sorting, lotus-notes

I would like to seek for your help.

I have these values in a view (ascending)

```
10D
11R
8A
8B
9C
```

But I want it to output the values in the "digit" dialog box in this manner:

```
8A
8B
9C
10D
11R
```

I tried using a hidden column (ascending order) having this as the code but it's getting error.

```
@length(digit)
```

Do note that the view has many forms associated to it.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Is your format fix, first integer then char

Comment: Hi @PramodYadav, no. I also have 6, 7, without char.

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you need the sort for the items with number prefixes to be G1, G2, G3, G4 ...G11, G12, etc. I would add a hidden sort column to the view with something like this:

```
wkey := SortKey;
lnum := @TextToNumber(@Left(wkey;1));

@If(@IsError(lnum); @Do(
    ch := @Left(wkey; 1);
    npart := @Right(wkey; ch);
    @Return(ch + @Right("00" + npart; 2))
); @Do(
    ch := @Right(wkey;1);
    npart := @Left(wkey; ch);
    @Return(@Right("00" + npart; 2) + ch))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try it with 2 hidden column.
If the field has the Name "id", for teh the first hiden column you use the formula `@toNumber(id)`.
If you have also values which begin with a character you can use this Formular for the first hidden column

```
@If(@Contains(@Text(@ToNumber(id));"Text");@Text(@ToNumber(id)) + id;@ToNumber(id))
```

This case is not shown in the Picture belos

For the second hidden column you use the formula `@Text(id)`.
And in the column which you want see, you Show the Field id.

[the view, the first two column you shuld hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZqZO.jpg)

[first hidden column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbvZB.jpg)

[second hidden column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjOX2.jpg)

[column you want display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrWcU.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for this. I apologize but there is also values which have a char prefix: G14, G17, etc.

Comment: Ok, and what is than the sort order? Interg first or char firs?
If you have your example, 10D, 11R, 8A, 8B, 9C and G14, how would you like the Output?
8A, 8B, 9C, 10D, 11R, G14 or G14,8A, 8B, 9C,10D, 11R ?

Comment: Hi @OliC, would like to have the first one as the output.

Comment: If you have also values which begin with a character you can use this Formular for the first hidden column
@If(@Contains(@Text(@ToNumber(id));"Text");@Text(@ToNumber(id)) + id;@ToNumber(id))

Comment: Im getting error: cannot convert text to a number for the first column for those with G13, G14

Comment: Ok, but the first column is a  hidden column, so the error is no Problem. The formula use the error message for sorting. If you look on the formula, you see that if the column contains a text with the string "Text" it use the Formular + id field, if not, it use the formula @ToNumber(id).
Can you Show Picture of your view